# 'To' field when parsing email in Python

Tags: python, parsing, email

I'm using the python standard library's email module to parse email. Something like this allows me to determine sender:

```
msg = email.message_from_string(data)
sender = msg.get_unixfrom()
```

But I'm having trouble determining who the mail is for.

Thoughts?

Comment: Note that `sender` in your example is the ["envelope from"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_from) of the message, not the "From:" header of the message.

Answer (score 6):

You can access all headers of the message [by index](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.__getitem__), e.g. `msg["From"]`. In the case of the recipient, use `msg.get_all("To")` because there might be multiple values.

Also note the following:

> Headers are stored and returned in case-preserving form but are matched case-insensitively.

Answer (score 1):

Example interactive session:

```
>>> import email
>>> msg = email.message_from_string("from: me\nto: you\n\nTest\n")
>>> msg.get_all('to')
['you']
>>> msg['to']
'you'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `__getitem__(name)` where name is the name of the header field you want to retrieve; in this case "To", "Cc" and "Bcc".

more information is available at: http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html

Comment: You can escape underscores with a backslash. Or use ticks to mark it as code ;)

Comment: Bcc header will be deleted before delivery, as far as i know it exists only in smtp session

Answer (score 0):

[`email.message.Message.get_all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_all) will get all values for the given header name.

```
print msg.get_all('to')
```